# Не работает роутинг на хостинге

Tags: c#, .net, asp

Делаю бота для телеграма. Взял [пример](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/tree/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook) веб-приложения с вебхуками.

Есть класс, отвечающий за настройку вебхука (вообще, что он делает, в данном случае, не так важно):

```
public class WebhookController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromServices] HandleUpdateService handleUpdateService,
                                          [FromBody] Update update)
    {
        await handleUpdateService.OnUpdate(update); // реакция на обновление
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

В `Startup.cs` настраивается роутинг для вызова этого метода по адрессу `домен/bot/токен`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute( // настройка роутинга для метода WebhookController.Post
            "tgwebhook",
            $"bot/{_botConfiguration.Token}",
            new { controller = "Webhook", action = nameof(WebhookController.Post) });

        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

`_botConfiguration` подтягивается из файлов конфигурации, которые я специально, для избежания ошибок на этом этапе, сделал идентичными для разработки и публикации.

При локальном запуске я без проблем через `Postman`-а могу послать POST-запрос по адресу `https://127.0.0.1:81/bot/токен`. Однако, когда я публикую сайт на хостинг (там вроде IIS 10), при POST-запросе `https://user19598.realhost-free.net/bot/токен` я получаю в ответ 404.

Веб-конфиг:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\,?" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: А в логах сервера что?

Comment: @aepot там я нашёл только список запросов с кодами ответов

Comment: То есть, запрос приходит или нет? Сервер видит его? Сравните логи домашнего сервера и хостового, одинаково ли они реагируют на запросы. Релизная и дебаг конфигурации сервера у вас точно одинаковые в плане сервисов? Соберите релизную локально и перепроверьте.